# A bitwise shortcut for calculating the signed result of `(x - y) / z`, given unsigned operands

Tags: bit-manipulation, unsigned, signed, twos-complement, integer-division

I'm looking for a neat way (most likely, a "bitwise shortcut") for calculating the signed value of the expression `(x - y) / z`, given unsigned operands `x`, `y` and `z`.

Here is a "kinda real kinda pseudo" code illustrating what I am currently doing (please don't mind the actual syntax being "100% perfect C or C++"):

```c
int64 func(uint64 x, uint64 y, uint64 z)
{
    if (x >= y) {
        uint64 result = (x - y) / z;
        if (int64(result) >= 0)
            return int64(result);
    }
    else {
        uint64 result = (y - x) / z;
        if (int64(result) >= 0)
            return -int64(result);
    }
    throwSomeError();
}
```

Please assume that I don't have a larger type at hand.

I'd be happy to read any idea of how to make this simpler/shorter/neater.

Comment: It looks pretty clean and neat to me. Those nested if statements look 100% redundant to me however.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk: How so? Without them, if `result` is larger than 2^63-1, then the wrong answer will be returned

Comment: Well, it will be throwing an error when attempting to call, for example, `func(0, 1<<63, 1)`, which is technically within boundaries, as the result (`-(1<<63)`) is within the range of `int64`. So my code isn't even perfect for that specific case. But those checks are still very relevant.

Comment: Ahh, thanks, I see now. That can only happen if z == 1.

Comment: Do you have to worry about possibly negative z?

Comment: @RaymondChen: How can `uint64 z` be negative?

Comment: I was under the assumption that `x`, `y`, and `z` were really signed integers, just represented as unsigned. But now I understand that they really are unsigned from the start, and you are performing the calculations as "mathematical integers" (unlimited precision).

Comment: @RaymondChen: It's actually limited precision. But the mathematical value of `(x-y)/z` can nevertheless be negative, and that's what I'm trying to do. If it exceeds the boundaries of `int64`, then I allow failure (of some sort, TBD, but not relevant in the scope of this question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a shortcut, by using a bitwise trick for conditional-negation twice (once for the absolute difference, and then again to restore the sign).

I'll use some similar non-perfect C-ish syntax I guess, to match the question.

First get a mask that has all bits set iff `x < y`:

```
uint64 m = -uint64(x < y);
```

`(x - y)` and `-(y - x)` are actually the same, even in unsigned arithmetic, and conditional negation can be done by using the definition of two's complement: `-a = ~(a - 1) = (a + (-1) ^ -1)`. `(a + 0) ^ 0` is of course equal to `a` again, so when `m` is -1, `(a + m) ^ m = -a` and when `m` is zero, it is `a`. So it's a conditional negation.

```
uint64 absdiff = (x - y + m) ^ m;
```

Then divide as usual, and restore the sign by doing another conditional negation:

```
return int64((absdiff / z + m) ^ m);
```

Comment: Thank you. Any way to do this without the branch?

Comment: @bbbbbbbbb well maybe, it depends on the set of operations that you use. `-uint64(x < y)` could be done with compare/cmove, compare/setcc, or a direct compare-to-mask, depending on what's available. Alternatively, the whole absdiff could be done with two saturating subtractions and a bitwise OR, but for example SSE2, which has some unsigned saturating subtractions, doesn't have a 64bit saturating subtraction. Without any of that, it could still be done, but it wouldn't be pretty.

Comment: sub/sbb is a good sequence too, the result of the sub can then be reused for the `x - y` which needs to happen anyway.

Comment: The `_subborrow_u64` intrinsic will let you calculate the mask without a branch. `_subborrow_u64(_subborrow_u64(0, x, y, &signeddiff), 0, 0, &m);`